# How can I get CSS dense work in this grid (not masonry)

Tags: css, grid

Can somebody help me figure out why `dense` doesn't work in this example? This is different than masonry examples in other questions. First of all, I'm trying to understand how `dense` works and why it doesn't work in this case. Second, what I'm trying to achieve is different than masonry examples as I'm trying to fit as many small elements as it could get in each **row** vs putting elements back to back from top to bottom (or left to right) to fill as many columns as possible in masonry.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4pt;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
.container div {
  background-color: #FAA;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.small {
  height: 100px;
}
.med {
  height: 200px;
}
.big {
  height: 400px;
}
.huge {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="small">1</div>
    <div class="huge">2</div>
    <div class="small">3</div>
    <div class="med">4</div>
    <div class="small">5</div>
    <div class="huge">6</div>
    <div class="big">7</div>
    <div class="med">8</div>
    <div class="small">9</div>
    <div class="huge">10</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting it to automatically fit small items into the same row as many as possible

Comment: *I'm expecting it to automatically fit small items into the same row as many as possible* --> that's THE definition of "masonry layout" and "dense" has nothing to do with it. It won't do what you want.

Comment: That's not what masonry is. In masonry there are no gaps in a row at all, whereas dense should "try" to fit as many as possible and sometimes leaves gaps in the rows if it cannot. You cannot close a question just because it "looks like" another one. I'm sure there are people out there who would know the difference here.